# htaccess RewriteRule problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a web page which works fine on live server. However some links to files (jpg, pdf and others) which are created with cms editor contain relative paths.
When I run that page on my local test server which serves the pages out of a sub folder of localhost the relative paths to the files are wrong since they are missing the subfolder at the beginning. The html page loads fine. It's just some files in it that have wrong path and won't load.

page loads from http://localhost/level1/

files are trying to load from http://localhost/level2/ and I get 404s.

They should be loading from http://localhost/level1/level2/

So I setup a RewriteRule to correct the path but no matter what I have tried I can't get it to work. I have tried various flags including [R,L] but nothing changes the URI in the html.

currently I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/level2/(.*)$ /level1/level2/$1 [R]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like those links are *not* relative paths but absolute ones (starting with a leading slash (`/`). That is why the issue occurs at all. Relative paths make much more sense.

This would be the version to be used inside your http servers host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/level2/(.*)$ /level1/level2/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here the version for `.htaccess` style files (note the missing leading slash):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^level2/(.*)$ /level1/level2/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You could use a version that can be used in *both* situations:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?level2/(.*)$ /level1/level2/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note however that in general one should *always* prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configurations. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow down the server, often for nothing. `.htaccess` style files only offer a last option for those who are using a really cheap web hosting provider. Or for situations where a web application has to write its own rewrite rules, which obviously is a security nightmare on its own...

Comment: in my ignorance I thought rewrite engibe was on since it is switched on in base apache conf file on my local setup. However,  I find that becasue I'm using virtual hosts for several domains I need to use "RewriteOptions inherit" in each virtual domain.

Comment: That is something I do not understand. Out of two reasons: 1. if the engine was not enabled for some virtual domain, then you should have gotten an error. Didn't you check your error log file? and 2. if you use virtual hosts locally, then why the fuzz with the different levels? Just define a virtual host that mirrors the situation you have in the production environment!

Comment: the problem as you pointed out was the leading / on the few files setup via the cms editor file uploader which is putting the leading / there.
I have taken the leading slashes out so paths are relative and everything works OK on my local setup.

Comment: in my ignorance I thought rewrite engine was on in base apache conf file. It was but seems I need "RewriteOptions inherit" in each virtual host domain.
Having said and done that the problem was not solved with your or my own attempts. It also starts a problem in IE11 where using refresh (F5 or ctrl+F5) casuses css and js files to not load. But using a link in the page it works fine. Maybe something to do with RewriteBase.
Anyhow, for now I switched it off and removed leading / from files in code and all is working OK.
I'll investigate the Refresh / rewrite problem at a later time.

Thanks

Comment: I just use one local virtual host and run all sites out of their own sub folder. I never ran into this problem before and I would forever be creating new virtual hosts in apache vhosts conf.
But agreed it would have solved the problem.
Thanks again

Comment: The refresh issue sounds like the typical flawed behavior of MS-IEs caching strategy.

Comment: Using virtual hosts is often easier than using subfolders. And _much_ more elegant, since you can have separate configurations.